# Ensure that code within CompletableFuture callback executes after

Tags: java, concurrency, vert.x, preemption

Say I have this:

```
public void foo(){
     CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).execute(() -> {                 
         doSomethingA();                
      });       
      doSomethingB();        
}
```

Is there any guarantee that doSomethingB(); will always run before doSomethingA();? Something tells me with *thread pre-emption*, it's possible, although unlikely, that doSomethingA() could be run first?

Comment: You might ask why I need the code in doSomethingB() to always be run first - I could just put doSomethingB() above the CompletableFuture call - but this is a classic asynchronous coding situation and in order to prevent *zalgo*, I do need to make sure certain calls that are registered after an async call do get registered before the async callback fires.

Comment: Note that in Node.js `doSomethingB()` would always run first, but I don't think is a guarantee in other runtimes.

Comment: "it's possible, although unlikely, that doSomethingA() could be run first?" This is correct. "Note that in Node.js doSomethingB() would always run first" That's because it's effectively single-threaded. Now the question is - if `doSomethingB` is so quick to always finish <1ms, then just put it above. If it's not quick enough to finish in 1ms, then you can have it start and not finish before `doSomethingA` starts, in which case you can add a semaphore / latch to control the ordering.

Comment: Have a look at Akka (https://akka.io/). It uses message-based concurrency. You define your actors (pieces of code to run), and asynchronously run them (send messages to actors).

Comment: @Perdi yeah I am working with Vert.x, will take another look at Akka

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel does Akka somehow avoid the problem described in the OP? I would think pre-emptive scheduling would always invite this problem, but maybe not in Akka?

Comment: Very careful here. You broke synchronicity therefore before-after guarantees are lost. No matter which library you use. However, in a single-threaded environment you are lucky and the before-after guarantee still applies.

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel does Akka guarantee anything? Is Akka better than Vertx in this regard?

Comment: Not at this level. You have to wrap up your sleeves and use the libraries facilities to ensure registration has been performed before the callback is run

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel yeah I figured. Node.js works at the language level to do async programming, but Java not so much. I wonder if frameworks like Akka or Vertx could somehow so alter threads that they can't get pre-empted. There are some calls in Vertx that always go to the next tick of the event loop. But I think the question is - can the event loop only start when all the currently scheduled code has finished running? idk

Comment: @AlexanderMills what "the event loop" are you talking about? In Java, there is no event loop unless you create your own one. Better tell what you need to accomplish, and we'll tell how to do it.

Comment: @AlexanderMills the notion of 'zalgo' is something completely alien to (and useless in) truly parallel programming, including Java programming. I program in java since 1996 and have learned `zalgo` only today. Forget it and think in terms of parallel programming: threads, semaphores, locks, happens-before etc.

Comment: @Alexei I am talking about the event loop which exists in Vertx, and yes Zalgo is real! Zalgo is just a specific kind of race condition.

Comment: @AlexanderMills in Vertex, there are many event loops, working on multiple threads, so the reasoning typical to single-threaded event loops like that in Node.js is not applicable. So the best approach is to consider Vertex' event loops just as an ordinary thread pool. To avoid race conditions, Java has rich set of tools. Use them, and your solution will be generic, which you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no guarantee, when on a machine which has multiple processors, that doSomethingB() would ***always*** execute before doSomethingA(). Though it will likely happen 99.999999999% of the time.

I noticed in some of your comments a reference to an "Event Loop". In Java there is no native concept of an Event Loop like there is in, say, Node and Javascript. If you have 4 threads, with four processors, and you submit four tasks, all four tasks will run in parallel.

Comment: Yeah I was talking about the Vertx event loop, will make sure the question is tagged with vertx

Comment: yeah that 99.999999% scares me, because on a long running server its bound to happen eventually

Comment: I haven't worked with Vertx, but it looks to be a framework for managing parallel/concurrent executions. If Vertx has its own event loop and event dispatch thread, you'd want to use the tools provided by vertx. In your example, you're using vanilla Java which wouldn't have the event loop.

Comment: It's Java, so a thread can still be pre-empted - in my case I am writing a library that could be used by Akka or Vertx or any other Java env. So I am looking for generic solution. Hence the question.