# Force re-use of thread by CompletableFuture

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor, completable-future

I am making critical use of:

```
 CompletableFuture
  .delayedExecutor(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).execute(() -> {});
```

From what I have read online, it's common for this to use a new thread for every call. I am wondering if there is a way to re-use a thread instead of creating new threads?

**Update**:

I wasn't clear - I want to use `CompletableFuture`, but I want `CompletableFuture` to reuse a certain thread, instead of managing its own threads.

I see this question:
[CompletableFuture reuse thread from pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39165655/completablefuture-reuse-thread-from-pool/39166632)

but it recommends using an environment variable - I am wondering if there is a way to do this programmatically.

Comment: How many processors do you have?

Comment: Why aren't you using an `ExecutorService` to dispatch that?

Comment: I can use ExecutorService to dispatch, but I didn't know I could do that, can you add an answer showing how?

Comment: @shmosel 8 processors .. this code is going to run on many different machines not just my laptop at home or whatever

Comment: Then it should use a thread pool out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

**Executor** new Thread is created for every set of tasks

> An Executor is normally used instead of explicitly creating threads. For example, rather than invoking new Thread(new(RunnableTask())).start() for each of a set of tasks, you might use: for each of a set of tasks

```
Executor executor = anExecutor;
executor.execute(new RunnableTask1());
executor.execute(new RunnableTask2());
```

So if you want to reuse the threads, create a thread pool by using `ExecutorService` or `ThreadPoolExecutor`, so one of the threads from the pool will execute the runnable tasks.

If all the threads are busy, tasks will be queued up to a certain limit and after that will get rejected through a `RejectedExecutionException`.

**Example**

```
public class NewMain { 

    private static final ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        ex.execute(r);

        CompletableFuture<Void> c = CompletableFuture.runAsync(r, ex);
    }
}
```

**Jdk-8** Use `CompletableFuture.runAsync` and pass runnable, Executor

**public static  CompletableFuture runAsync(Supplier supplier,
                                                   Executor executor)**

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously completed by a task running in the given executor after it runs the given action.

Comment: Hmmm but how does this integrate with CompletableFuture? TMK, CompletableFuture uses its own threads, sometimes many threads. My goal was to tell CompletableFuture to use threads from a specific pool, so I am not sure if this answers my question.

Comment: I updated the OP to make the question a little clearer, let me know if it is or not

Answer (score 1):

> From what I have read online, it's common for this to use a new thread for every call.

(1) It's the case only if the machine doesn't support parallelism or you made it to not support it by setting the system property [`java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) to `0` or `1`.

> 8 processors

(2) If the machine does support parallelism, [`ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--) is used and the parallelism level is set, I guess, to the number of available processors (which can be determined by [`Runtime#availableProcessors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors())).

In a scenario with 8 processors, 7-8 threads will probably be created to serve the common `ForkJoinPool`.

> I want to use `CompletableFuture`, but I want `CompletableFuture` to reuse a certain thread, instead of managing its own threads.

A `DelayedExecutor` just submits tasks to the underlying `Executor`, which is either a `ThreadPerTaskExecutor` (1) or a `ForkJoinPool` (2).

Fortunately, you can manually specify an `Executor` which will be employed by the `DelayedExecutor` to delegate tasks to.

```
Executor delayedExecutor = 
     CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, executor);
```

It gets us back to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54564377), where I [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54564526/4922375) that an `Executor` can be defined with a `ThreadFactory`.

```
Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(YourThreadClass::new);
```